# Gauss curvature using metric and Riemannian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I learnt that the Gauss curvature is given by:

$$K = \frac {eg - f^2}{EG - F^2}$$

where $E, F, G$ are coefficients of the first fundamental form and $e,f, g$ are coefficients of the second fundamental form.

However, in a proof that I am reading, I saw the equation:

$$K = \langle R(E_1,E_2)E_2, E_1 \rangle$$

for an orthonormal frame $(E_1, E_2)$ on a surface $M$, where $R$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_definitions) says that this is a definition for $K$ but I was wondering if there is a proof for this?

Comment: A proof for the equivalence of the two?

Comment: It's called the Gauss equation in classical surface theory.

Answer (score 3):

We can define a new quantity:
$$R(E_1,E_2,E_2,E_1):=\langle R(E_1,E_2)E_2,E_1\rangle$$
The Gauss equation allows us to say (since $E_1,E_2$ are orthonormal):
$$R(E_1,E_2,E_2,E_1)=\det(S)=K$$
Here, $S$ is the shape operator, and the Gauss equation is
$$R(E_1,E_2)E_2=\langle S(E_2),E_2\rangle S(E_1)-\langle S(E_1),E_2\rangle S(E_2)$$

Comment: How did you get $det(S)$ from your last equation?

Comment: @user145817 Read [this lecture notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/).